# Which software is used to write math and plot simple graphs at universities with functioning LTR capabilities?

Tags: math-software

I generally use MS word, but it lacks plotting functionality.
My university uses a software that allows them to write math, and plot graphs with labels, cases and divisions. Such a graph is attached below.
If someone recognizes it, it would be much appreciated! Thank you.

[image: Example Graph]

Comment: It's probably done with one of the graphing packages of LaTeX – the most common being `tikz` and `pstricks`.

Comment: The main software used to write math is LaTeX. Also Tikz is one library you can use to create plots in LaTeX documents.

Comment: If you are familiar with MATLAB and Python, it would be a good to plot whatever you want and embed the plot in latex or word.